# center content in a simple legend layout

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, android-fragments

I build a layout that overflows the google maps and it look like that: [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OqGNO.png)

so the problem that i get with the layout on the bottom is that i can't center all the conter it stays too much on the left side and i don't know really why.

I want to center the content but mantain the space with each elemnt(i consider the element the background color + the text).

How can i do it?

**here is my xml(that contains the map and the layout):**

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">



    <fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context="com.example.afcosta.inesctec.pt.android.MapsActivity" />


    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/newmarker"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:background="#FFFFFFFF"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Legenda"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/rand"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:background="#FFFFFFFF"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:weightSum="3"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/myPos"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#FFFFFFFF"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/newmarker_save1"
                    android:layout_width="20dp"
                    android:layout_height="20dp"
                    android:background="@color/red" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView2"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                    android:text="Utilizador" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/allFotos"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="left"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#FFFFFFFF"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/newmarker_save2"
                    android:layout_width="20dp"
                    android:layout_height="20dp"
                    android:background="@color/emerald" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/Fotos"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                    android:text="Fotos" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/Photo"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="left"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:background="#FFFFFFFF"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button2"
                    android:layout_width="20dp"
                    android:layout_height="20dp"
                    android:background="@color/yellow" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView9"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="Planta" />
            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

thanks!

Comment: Can you post the screenshot of items left orientated? android:layout_gravity="bottom|center_horizontal" should do the job

Comment: check it above, it is already there

Comment: try removing `android:layout_weight="1"` from textview2 and textview9  and give width as `wrap_content` and try

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to **wrap_content** your *Button* and you *TextView*, remove **android:layout_weight="1"** from the textView that lives beside your Button, then finally make sure that every single LinearLayout that wraps your Button and **TextView** are flagged as **android:gravity="center"** (this gravity is gonna be applied for its childs)

Also I strongly advise you replacing these linear layouts for Relatives to reduce your UI hierarchy

Try this.

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">



<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.afcosta.inesctec.pt.android.MapsActivity" />


<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/newmarker"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:background="#FFFFFFFF"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Legenda"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/rand"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:background="#FFFFFFFF"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:weightSum="3"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/myPos"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#FFFFFFFF"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/newmarker_save1"
            android:layout_width="20dp"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:background="@color/colorAccent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:text="Utilizador" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/allFotos"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#FFFFFFFF"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/newmarker_save2"
            android:layout_width="20dp"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:background="@color/colorAccent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/Fotos"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:text="Fotos" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/Photo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:background="#FFFFFFFF"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="20dp"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:background="@color/colorAccent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView9"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:text="Planta" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

I presume that's what you want, right?
[image]

Comment: or use Constraint layout. Reduce all unnecessary hierarchy

Comment: awesome, is constraint layout good to work with layout rows with recycle view? i always had that question xD

Comment: @afcosta007 absolutely.